# lua dissector for a float variable returns zero

Tags: lua, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to read a float variable from the buffer but i'm getting a zero value.
This is the code i used:

```
-- Create fields

str_format=string.format
p_Genie.fields = {}
local fields = p_Genie.fields
fields.number_field = ProtoField.float("p_Genie.number", "Number",base.DEC)

function addFloat32(tree, buf, start, name, floatSize)
    local rang = buf(start, floatSize)

    local ti = tree:add_le(fields.number_field, rang)
    ti:set_text(str_format("%s %f", name, rang:le_float())) 
    return floatSize
end
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your use of ProtoField.float is correct.  According to [Section 11.6.7.16 of the Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html#lua_class_ProtoField), the 3rd argument is an optional valuestring, not a base.  Maybe start by fixing that and see if it resolves your problem.